# Appending string using an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets say I have a field in the database called, `updateLog` and it contains data like this:

```
Staff A 24/10/2014 11:00
Hi your order is being picked.

Staff A 24/10/2014 08:00
Your order is being sent to the picking team.
```

Now lets say I want to add a new update for my customer? How do i append the following text using TSQL:

```
Staff A 24/10/2014 12:00
Order completed. Thankyou
```

I need to be able to add this update to the top of my field. It needs to follow the convention of my updates.

```
UPDATE CustUpdates
SET updateLog = 'Staff A 24/10/2014 12:00' + CHAR(13) + 'Order completed. Thankyou'
WHERE ORDERID = 'ORD001'
```

The problem with my attempt is that it will overwrite the contents of my field!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table status(orderid int, updatelog nvarchar(500))

insert into status values(1, 'your previous message')

declare @message nvarchar(500) = 'Staff A 24/10/2014 12:00' + CHAR(13) + 
  'Order completed. Thankyou '

update status 
set updatelog = @message + updatelog
where orderid = 1


select * from status
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/562d4/2

Comment: I think the message doesnt have a space in your results!

Comment: I didn't get you? you mean between message and updatelog there is no space?

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
UPDATE CustUpdates
   SET updateLog = 'Staff A 24/10/2014 12:00' + CHAR(13) + 'Order completed. Thankyou' + CHAR(13) + updateLog
 WHERE ORDERID = 'ORD001'
```